# Performing google image search from android app

Tags: android, google-custom-search, google-image-search

I am building an android app for finding book review. App functionality is likely taking a picture of the book cover with user mobile phone and instantly showing real time reviews from amazon.com or something.com. For this purpose i need to perform **Google Image Search** for finding the book's title. I have been studying about google's **Custom Search API**. But i have not find any solution for searching google with a image.

Does **Custom Search API** can search with image? If so how can i implement this to my app using **Custom Search API**?

Comment: maybe think of doing a "post" on google image search or extracting  text by using teseract engine and then doing a text search could help

Comment: @penta you are talking about **OCR** .

Comment: yes, that is the only thing which comes to my mind to tackle this problem